# What is common thing to handle for ios and android platform in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I've been building react-native for android at beginning and never been into IOS as I don't have project that use IOS at that moment and I don't own IOS or MacOS. And I'm clueless of what is difference between IOS and Android in general. I'm currently need to develop my app to be able to use by both Android and IOS.

What are the common things that need to be handle? To be exact, check for Platform. From [maestral-solutions](https://medium.com/maestral-solutions/react-native-platform-specific-code-e217db5778f), it shows on stylesheet that the header height and margin top:-

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    height: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 76 : 100,
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 24,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: { backgroundColor: '#f00', paddingTop: 24},
      android: { backgroundColor: '#00f'}
    }),
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 24
  }
});
```

Is there any other common things to handle for IOS platform? Like status bar or tab navigation or icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SafeAreaView` instead of `View` for wrap.
for example:

```
render() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

If you wrap with `View` then the header will cutted when you are using iPhoneX since iPhoneX has different UI with others.

And also there are some other things different in style.

In iOS you should add `overflow: 'hidden'` for `borderRadius`. Means, you can only use `borderRadius` in Android but you can see the circular border after add `overflow: 'hidden'`. And I think the `backgroundColor` will works in `Text` component in Android but not in iOS.
Then you should care about `Alert.alert` in iOS. in Android you can normally use Alert and setState in the same time. But if you use Alert and setState in the same time then alert disappear right after show. For break down this you can use like this.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  Alert.alert('info', 'Testing');
}, 100);
this.setState({spinner: false});
```

You can check this will works well in iOS too.